# I can't boot Windows 10 after removing ssd with elementary os

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, elementaryos

Context:

I bought my new pc and I installed Elementary OS on my ssd. After a while, I bought another SSD and I installed Windows 10 on it without issues. If I want select one, I choose the first boot from BIOS without issues, again.
Then, I extracted the Linux SSD and I want to join to Windows I can't.

This show a message like:

"insert booteable device and press key"

I did:
Insert USB, automatic repair. --> doesn't work
Insert USB, CMD and type:
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /scanos
bootrec /rebuildbcd
--> this show: The requested system device cannot be found.

Insert DVD and the same before --> message confirm good process but it doesn't work!!

I tried [Visual BCD Editor](https://www.boyans.net/) on Windows 10. it showed succesful message and but it didn't work too

If I put SSD on case and I connect by USB, I cant boot Windows!!!!

EDIT:
I tried too:
bcdedit /export C:\BCD_Backup
c:
cd boot
attrib bcd -s -h -r
ren c:\boot\bcd bcd.old
bootrec /rebuildbcd
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
exit

But When I type "cd boot" it shows "TThe system can not find the path specified"

How can I fix MBR???
I think I don't have because boot was installed on Linux SSD, then How can I make a new boot in Windows disk?

Summary:

two SSD, two OS. I installed first Linux, then Windows 10. I removed Linux SSD. I can't boot Windows 10

Comment: You probably have boot partition (with boot manager) on removed drive. You cant simply disconnect 2nd drive with 2nd system and expecting that will be work...

Answer (score 0):

Try make 500MB place before windows partition, then copy partition whit boot manager from removed drive, make it active and try boot...

Comment: I can't lose my data. To make a partition will not damage my data?

Comment: you can shrink partition using disk manager or third party software, but it is recommended to backup data first...

Comment: with linux live?

Comment: try first with windows 10

Comment: Could I make the boot partition in a pendrive? It would work for a while but How would I do that?

Comment: it is possible, try...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49187/discussion-between-mrquestion-and-adam-silenko).